Use the Windows PC as a middleware to access the restricted site
Assume my Windows PC has the ability to access the restricted.com site via a network adapter that only supports Windows. I want my other Linux PC to be able to access that site as well, but because that specific network adapter is only available on Windows, I can't configure it to work on the Linux PC. So I came up with this idea: when I access the site on the Linux PC, it will send the request to the Windows PC, which will then forward the request to the restricted site, receive the response, and send it back to the Linux PC. Is it possible, and if so, how can I do it? Both PCs are in the same LAN network.

Please provide more information, what's behind the domain? What IP does it resolve to (e.g. local) etc. Why can it be only accessed by the network adapter on the Windows PC (e.g. based on the MAC address)? If the network adapter doesn't use the network standard it's probably required to be known to come up with the correct solution since regular routing solutions probably won't work.

While there's ways to do this, If the site is restricted to specific machines for a reason, accessing it via another site might get you in trouble. Something like a SSH tunnel (in reverse?) VPN set up appropriately or even RDPing into the windows box might work, but depending on how secured the windows PC is and what they're monitoring, it might annoy whoever is restricting access to the site.
